# Regex for any word in text file

Tags: c#, regex

I need to capture every word in a text file separately. 
The words can be like ordinary words, numbers, numbers containing hyphens etc.

My criteria for a word is that whatever it may be it will either be separated by a space before another word or the word will end with dot.

I tried with `@"(\w+)+"` in C# but it fails to capture every word as defined above as well as things like `+-.,!@#$%^&*();\/|<>"'`.

The purpose is to create a unique list of words.

Comment: May be you are looking for `\b`

Comment: It is usually contains ordinary words, words joined with hyphens, dates separated by either hyphens, dots and slashes and things pointed out in the post. Very lengthy to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oM0wG3/3)

```
([^\s\.]+)\.?
```

means:

```
(    - beginning of capture
 [   - one of..
  ^  - none of the following characters
  \s - a space character (tab, space etc)
  \. - a literal dot
 ]
 +   - one or more of the previous block (in []) in a greedy way
)    - close of capture block
\.   - a literal dot
?    - zero or one
```

Which matches multiple non spaces (and not a dot), which could end in a dot (but will never include it).

Comment: The answer by @ergonaut solves my problem. It capture everything in my text file.

Comment: I have accepted this answer. Can I upvote this answer. And how to.do it.

Comment: Thank you. I have already done that. I thought there is something else to do.

Comment: Could you please explain how this regex works? It would be helpful to many others. @ergonaut.

Answer (score 2):

You want `[^.\s]+` which matches any sequence of characters which are not whitespace or dot.

Answer (score 0):

use string.split() and define your delimiters to space, dot and/or new line.
you can use any Regex as delimiter as well.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Regex contains a "word boundary" character (`\b`). This includes spaces and punctuation. Since your criteria includes numbers (is it ASCII-only?) this is probably the best solution for your specific case.

You can try this regex: `\b([^\b]+)\b`

This matches a word-boundary, and then one or more non-boundary characters, up to the next word boundary.